# How to set the form Location in Windows Forms, .net 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I am migrating the Windows Forms application written in C# to .net 3.5 and it appears that setting the Location property to 0,0 won't do the trick to position it in the top left corner. It's about 10 pixels down from the top.

Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also set [StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) to `FormStartPosition.Manual`.